# MediaPlayer.framework (MPMoviePlayerController) playing movie from URL that requires access credentials

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsurlcredential

i am having problems with playing movie from URL that has basic http authentification.

Here is code:

```
NSURLCredential *credential = [[NSURLCredential alloc]
                               initWithUser:@"user"
                               password:@"password"
                               persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace = [[NSURLProtectionSpace alloc]
                                             initWithHost:@"moze.dyndns.org"
                                             port:80
                                             protocol:@"http"
                                             realm:nil
                                             authenticationMethod:NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic];

[[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] setDefaultCredential:credential forProtectionSpace:protectionSpace];


NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://moze.dyndns.org/test/test.mov"];
moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
[moviePlayerController.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [moviePlayerController moviePlayer];
mp.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
[mp prepareToPlay];
[[moviePlayerController moviePlayer] play];
```

I am getting error "The operation couldn't be completed. (MediaPlayerErrorDomain error -1013.)", errorLog in NULL, just like accessLog too.

I am using a apache server with AuthType Basic, credentials are right, tested them on web browser. There are no problems with playback if authentification is disabled.

Please help, I can't find what is wrong.

Comment: It's entirely possible that the movie player doesn't consult URL credential storage, because it's not using the URL loading system internally :(

Comment: So is there any other way to play media from url that requires authentication?

Comment: I would love to know if you came up with anything on this. I agree with Mike Abdullah about not using the credentials you are setting. I am seeing the same thing. I also have the problem that once I set the credentials successfully I can't delete them. None of the solutions I have found have helped.

Comment: I ended up with different approach - generating temporary, open links, that would allow only certain amount of connections.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get `MPMoviePlayerController` to do the authentication challenge properly, even thought the Apple docs say otherwise.  The VERY hacky solution I came up with was to use Apple's `CustomHTTPProtocol` to intercept the response and provide the authentication challenge response.  I believe the original purpose for this protocol was to handle authentication for `UIWebViews`.

Link to `CustomHTTPProtocol`:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CustomHTTPProtocol/Listings/Read_Me_About_CustomHTTPProtocol_txt.html

My interface declaration:

```
@interface SampleViewController() <CustomHTTPProtocolDelegate>
```

Instantiation of `MPMoviePlayerController` within my `SampleViewController`:

```
NSString *fullURLString = @"http://www.samplesite.com/samplemovie.mp4";
NSURL *fullURL = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURLString];

[CustomHTTPProtocol setDelegate:self];
[CustomHTTPProtocol start];

NSURLCredential *credential = [[NSURLCredential alloc]
                              initWithUser:@"username"
                              password:@"password"
                              persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace = [[NSURLProtectionSpace alloc]
                                        initWithHost:fullURL.host
                                        port:80
                                        protocol:fullURL.scheme
                                        realm:@"your-realm"
                                        authenticationMethod:NSURLAuthenticationMethodDefault];
[[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] setDefaultCredential:credential forProtectionSpace:protectionSpace];

self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fullURL];
[self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:NO];
[self.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded];
[self.moviePlayer.view setFrame:self.sampleView.bounds];
[self.moviePlayer.backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.9 alpha:1.0]];
[self.moviePlayer.view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
[self.sampleView addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
```

Also in my `SampleViewController`, I have a couple delegate methods.  For basic authentication, it's pretty simple:

```
- (BOOL)customHTTPProtocol:(CustomHTTPProtocol *)protocol canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace
{
    BOOL canAuth = ([[protectionSpace authenticationMethod] isEqual:NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic] &&
                    [[protectionSpace realm] isEqualToString:@"your-realm"]);
    return canAuth;
}

- (void)customHTTPProtocol:(CustomHTTPProtocol *)protocol didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    NSURLCredential *newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"username"
                                               password:@"password"
                                            persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

After you call `start`, all http and https requests go through the `CustomHTTPProtocol` module

I didn't include `CustomHTTPProtocol` since Apple provides the source and it's really long.  I made some changes to make it work with ARC but it's mostly the same code.

Hopefully this works for you.